# VBA-code to insert link to a file in an email sent by Lotus / IBM Notes

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes, lotus

Based on code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455524/vba-insert-body-of-email-above-signature-using-lotus-notes) on StackOverflow I am able to send an email from IBM Notes with Excel VBA.
The only thing missing in the code is how to send the email with a link to a file on a shared folder. I have looked all around looking for code but unfortunately have not found it. I am  desperately looking for code in the same format as the code below. The code below includes my signature while other code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461949/how-to-open-a-lotus-notes-new-mail-and-send) one does not since I do not have a HTML-signature and also cannnot create it.

Please help me to include a filename and a link to that file in the emailbody with emailBody(3).
Another approach is ok with me, as long as I still have the signature as well as the link to the file. Just to be clear: I do not need to include an attachment, but a (hyper)link to a file.
I would think the code should be very simple, but unfortunately it does not seem to be so.

My code is as follows, only the LinkToFile part is not working:

```
    Sub Send_Email_With_IBM_Notes()

Dim UserName As String, MailDbName As String, Recipient As String
Dim Maildb As Object, MailDoc As Object, session As Object
Dim emailBody(1 To 3) As String, EmailBodyTotal As String
Dim notesUIDoc As Object  
Dim FileName as string, LinkToFile as string

FileName = "Excel-File"
LinkToFile = "Location/Excel-File.xlsx"

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False

    Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    UserName = session.UserName
    MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
    Set Maildb = session.GetDatabase("", MailDbName)
    If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
    Else
        Call Maildb.OPENMAIL
    End If

    Recipient = "Email Addresses"
    
    emailBody(1) = "Good morning,"
    emailBody(2) = "Please see below link:"
    emailBody(3) = FileName & LinkToFile
    EmailBodyTotal = Join(emailBody, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
    
    ' Create New Mail and Address Title Handlers
    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CreateDocument
    MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
    MailDoc.SendTo = Recipient
    MailDoc.subject = FileName

    'Displays email message without sending; user needs to click Send
    Set workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
    Set notesUIDoc = workspace.EDITDOCUMENT(True, MailDoc)
    Call notesUIDoc.gotofield("Body") 'Go to the body, keep your signature.
    Call notesUIDoc.InsertText(EmailBodyTotal & vbCrLf) 'Add text above signature
  
    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing

    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: File links are usually prefixed with either a shared drive letter "W:\" or a full UNC path "\\My-NAS-Box\shared\folder\path\filename.xlsx".

Comment: @RobMason, thank you for your answer, would you be able to supply code as to how I would include this in my code? I am able to put the location of the file like you mentioned in the email, but I am not able to create a link to the file.

Comment: Have not worked with lotus notes for eons now :D Did you try googling it? [EX: 1](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/need-to-embed-hyperlink-in-vba-email-lotus-notes.1051063/)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, thank you for your reply. I googled a lot trying to fix this issue. I did find and used the code from your link before. It even worked for me, but then my signature was missing from the email. It seems I can either create an email with a link (HTML-code) but without signature (because I do not have an HTML-signature) or create an email with signature but without a link. I cannot get it to work with both signature and link. It's driving me crazy, because it should be simple. I am not the type of guy to accept it is not working.

Comment: I would have loved to help you out but do not have access to lotus notes... sorry

Comment: @Willem, the client should put the link in automatically for you when you send the mail.

Comment: If the email is in HTML then I would think just the usual <a href="file://path/to/the/filename.xlsx">Filename</a> would suffice.

Comment: @Duston, thank you, but the email is not in HTML.

Comment: @RobMason, how would the link be automatically put in? Can you please provide the code? When I put in the location of the file, it does not create a link to it. It only shows the location. In the menu of IBM Notes there is an option to create a link, I would like to know how this can be done with VBA.

Comment: Links are an HTML thing.  If the email is text only, then there is no such thing as a link, all you{ll ever get is the name of the file.

Comment: @Duston when I create the link afterwards (when the email was created with VBA) it is still possible to create the link manually, but so far not with VBA. So to me it should also be possible with VBA, but maybe with Sendkeys or something.

Comment: What if you try `NStream.WriteText HTML & Maildb.GETPROFILEDOCUMENT("CalendarProfile").GETITEMVALUE("Signature")(0)` or something in those lines?

Comment: AFAIK the NotesUIDocument class provides no methods for link (hotspot) creation. What you can try is creating a valid URL (file://...) and adding it as plain text. With some luck the system will recognise the URL and make it into a link

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks, but it seems I have no HTML-signature, therefor the .GETPROFILEDOCUMENT("CalendarProfile").GETITEMVALUE("Signature")(0) is empty. It does not add my signature in the email. I tried creating a HTML-signature, but it is not possible with IBM Lotus Notes 9 which I use.

Comment: @AFAIK, thank you, it does put in the file location in the email, but it does not convert it to a link.

Comment: @afaik I think that explains it. If there is no method to create a link with the NotesUIDocument, then the only way is creating an HTML-email with the disadvantage that it will not add my signature.

Comment: The body field is a NotesRichTextItem which has an EmbeddedObjects property that one would use to attach a file.  But you said that's not what you wanted to do, you want to put some text into a text email and have it magically turn into a link.  If it's just text, that won't happen any sooner than you can create a link in Notepad.

Comment: When you put in a plain text link into an email (and that is what you are doing in your example) turning it into a link is a feature of the receiving email client. It is not a feature of the code that is sending the link.  I.e., if you put the link in with the correct syntax (e.g., \\server\\path\path\filename ) using the InsertT. xt method as described above, and the receiving client does not convert it to a link, then maybe you can look at the settings on the receiving side., but of course that's not always practical. The alternative, given in Karl-Henry's answer gives you much more control,

Comment: @RichardSchwartz thank you for your comment. I sent multiple emails to myself for testing, but it does not convert a location of a file to a link, not when I write it as HTML "<a href='file://" & LinkToFile & "'>" & FileName & "</a><br>" nor when I write "file:///" & LinkToFile or whatever variant I used. When it comes to the answer from Karl-Henry, unfortunately my knowledge is not sufficient to implement this.

Comment: You admit that you don't have the knowledge to pursue the recommended solution, and then you conclude that the product has "few options". Thanks for starting my day with a laugh!

Comment: @RichardSchwartz you are right. But perhaps you agree it is not easy creating code in VBA for something seemingly simple. I also use VBA for Outlook which is less complex and better documented.

Comment: It is well documented and not very complex. Not different than any other code that is interacting with COM.

Comment: I'll admit that it's hard to find the relevant documentation for 25-year-old features of a product that's been around for more than 30 years, especially if you're not familiar with the vocabulary, but now that I look more closely, it's just hard. In Karl-Henry's sample code, the AppendDocLink method is not what you need. There isn't an AppendHotspotLink method in the NotesRichTextItem class, and that's what you'd actually need.  Most Notes/Domino developers would probably do this by building an HTML message using the NotesMIME classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the COM interface/classes instead of OLE. When using COM you have access to all the backend classes in Notes/Domino, which is much more flexible and powerful.  Instead of `Notes.NotesSession` you would use `Lotus.NotesSession`.

You can then (probably) use the NotesRichText class to insert a hotspot link to the file on the network share (assuming the recipient has the network folder mapped identical to you).

Here is a link to a Lotusscript Class for creating email notification from an application, you should be able to adapt it for VBA without any big problems:
http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-mail-notification-class/

*Update 2021-06-22:* Here is some code. All this can be found in [the online help](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_4_LOTUSSCRIPT_NOTES_CLASSES_REFERENCE.html).  You should look closer at the `NotesRichTextItem` class and `NotesDocument` class.
Just replace everything after the comment starting with *Displays email message without sending* with something like this:

```
Dim body As Object
Set body = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body") 
Call body.AppendText("Good morning,")
Call body.AddNewLine(2)
Call body.AppendText("Please see below link:")
Call body.AddNewLine(1)
Call body.AppendDocLink(LinkToFile,"[Link to File]","Click here...")
Call MailDoc.Send()
```

If you don't get the link to work withthe code above you can just insert the link URL using the AppendText() method, and hopefully the recipient email client will display the link properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I looked at the code but I am not sure how to use it.
What would your code look like similar to the code mentioned in my question?

Comment: Karl-Henry, thank you but when I use the CreateRichTextItem it leaves out my signature.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all for your contributions!

It is not a 100% solution unfortunately but it works most of the time when I use Application.Sendkeys and also NumLockOn because the sendkeys switch NumLock off. The  Timevalue in between the Sendkeys is very important!!

This is my (more or less) working code for anyone who is interested:

```
    Sub Send_Email_With_IBM_Notes()
    
    Dim UserName As String, MailDbName As String, Recipient As String 
    Dim Maildb As Object, MailDoc As Object, session As Object 
    Dim emailBody(1 To 4) As String 'changed
    Dim EmailBodyTotal As String 
    Dim notesUIDoc As Object   
    Dim FileName as string, LinkToFile as string
    
    FileName = "Excel-File" LinkToFile = "Location/Excel-File.xlsx"
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    
        Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
        UserName = session.UserName
        MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
        Set Maildb = session.GetDatabase("", MailDbName)
        If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
        Else
            Call Maildb.OPENMAIL
        End If
    
        Recipient = "Email Addresses"
        
        emailBody(1) = "Good morning,"
        emailBody(2) = "Please see below link:"
        emailBody(3) = FileName 
        emailBody(4) = LinkToFile 'changed
        EmailBodyTotal = Join(emailBody, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
        
        ' Create New Mail and Address Title Handlers
        Set MailDoc = Maildb.CreateDocument
        MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
        MailDoc.SendTo = Recipient
        MailDoc.subject = FileName
    
        'Displays email message without sending; user needs to click Send
        Set workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
        Set notesUIDoc = workspace.EDITDOCUMENT(True, MailDoc)
        Call notesUIDoc.gotofield("Body") 'Go to the body, keep your signature.
        Call notesUIDoc.InsertText(EmailBodyTotal & vbCrLf) 'Add text above signature

    'The whole part below is new ***
    AppActivate ("Notes")
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys "{Left}"
    Application.SendKeys "+{HOME}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys "^x"
    Application.SendKeys "{BS}"
    Application.SendKeys "{BS}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys "+{HOME}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys ("{F10}M") 'Application.SendKeys "^M" does not work!!
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys "y"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys "^v"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys "~"
    NumLockOn
    'Part is new until here ***

        Set Maildb = Nothing
        Set MailDoc = Nothing
        Set session = Nothing
    
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True End With
    
    End Sub

Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

Sub NumLockOn() 
Dim NumLockState As Boolean
Let NumLockState = CBool(GetKeyState(vbKeyNumlock) And 1)
If NumLockState = False Then
SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
End If
End Sub
```